# При загрузке страницы 1 секунда показывается верстка без стилей

Tags: angular4

Проект на Angular 4. При первоначальной загрузке странице с начало на 1 сек показывается ломанная верстка, тексты без стилей а потом все становится нормально. Подскажите как с этим бороться?

Comment: Если вы спрашиваете "что я делаю не так?", то должны показать что именно вы *делаете*. Иначе, при текущем объеме информации в вопросе, можно сказать только "вы не так пользуетесь ангуляром".

Comment: Быть может Вам нужно [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)?

Comment: ngCloak - был в первом `angular`, ну это не страшно, можно писать например так: `{{user?.name}}`. Но тут мне кажется, что `html` грузится скорее `css` и потому такие скачки происходят.

Comment: Как загрузить в первую очередь `css`?

Comment: Скорее всего загрузка `css` стоит в самом конце шаблона/проекта, хотя ВСЕГДА должна быть первой, это гугл всех настращал так делать. Либо вешайте лоадер на всю страницу и не показывайте до тех пор, пока все не загрузится.

Answer (score 0):

при загрузке страницы не было данных, которые должны были показаться на странице. сделал все через `*ngIf="condition"`